# Execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger

Tags: apex, before-trigger, after-trigger

I'm just trying to call a post method if a multipicklist value is selected at the time of update. Not sure where exactly I'm making mistake

```
trigger RadarFirst on Patient_Satisfaction__c (before update) {
    for (Patient_Satisfaction__c cc : Trigger.new){
        if(cc.Patient_Relation__c.contains('Referred to Privacy Office')){
            RadarUpdate.postcallout(cc.id);
        }
    }
}
public class RadarUpdate {
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void postcallout(string Id) { 
    Patient_Satisfaction__c c = [select id, Name, Reporter_Phone__c,Reporter_First_Name__c,Reporter_Last_Name__c, Reporter_Email__c,
    Description_of_Feedback__c from Patient_Satisfaction__c where Patient_Relation__c ='Referred to Privacy Office' order by lastmodifiedDate desc limit 1];
    JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeObjectField('name', c.Name);
    gen.writeObjectField('incident_group_id', 7387);
    gen.writeObjectField('description',c.Description_of_Feedback__c);
    gen.writeFieldName('submitted_by');
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField('given_name',c.Reporter_First_Name__c);
    gen.writeStringField('surname', c.Reporter_Last_Name__c);
    gen.writeStringField('phone',c.Reporter_Phone__c);
    gen.writeStringField('email',c.Reporter_Email__c);
    gen.writeEndObject();
    String jsonS = gen.getAsString(); 
    System.debug('jsonMaterials'+jsonS);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.radarfirst.com/incidents');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    request.setHeader('User-agent', 'Salesforce-integration-client');
    request.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkExMjhHQ00ifQ.ayMT8mfFcCqkLyRGZsmodZfjcDpm-cGV0f3EJ_5NF-KU-DJ9DVWrUEzO4XUj4LjKLlU9ub9793bJuZdNkAGFJbUmecq7k3bfvVbJmuBwzlJny3wHnSLpf0khXR_UT5FIiKHji5iSmbE8Ojc-qfPwwn2B5S7SAZ44LAB-5ag7AErALqEOgSLYm0CKIGNvYGFmMsyJZbmgm4TD8FTfS3pcoC13lFo7V4U5kJOyFvEGqVAZLdT3p-VdxRIJ9qfbP8AlKrcIS4Znm-bq3c-iYqk7JfujalXBYgA_YltelAGrzFVjDMXcahFkaK71rGSFyaRv_O3xPqP3P9RG9Ga5ohx9vw.vCTJwd85Lq9TTslt.i6A8KSwPc6Nole_lwpo8pNDucVW0ENFbCSvTPajl3DpS0H6eb3C7ccyJYAT1Oi_s4RFtfluMHPOXl6CBKM_Qfj8RUQuLgnVBWj16CJeZm1fXvt0.wJKuy-m5GsNs4d_ecc2e5A');
    request.setBody(jsonS);
    // Set the body as a JSON object
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's likely not enough context here to provide you with any help. When discussing errors, it's helpful to include the full text of the error message along with the stack trace (which contains a list of line numbers and classes that led to the error). About the only thing that could throw an NPE here is `cc.Patient_Relation__c.contains()`, if `Patient_Relation__c` happens to be null.

Comment: Yes it gives me error on that line.RadarFirst: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.RadarFirst: line 3, column 1

Comment: I'm new in Apex, how do i do a null check on Patient_Relation__c ? on which line i should add?  Thanks!

Comment: @SalmanShaik Please post code for RadarUpdate class to help with null pointer. Also please post the full error message.

Comment: Also here is how you can handle null exception https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327918&type=1&mode=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null pointer exceptions occur when we try to call a method or access a variable on something that is `null`.

So when you run into an NPE, the first question you need to ask yourself is "what on this line can possibly be null?"

In this case, it's relatively easy. The thing that must be null here is the `Patient_Relation__c` field.

Once you figure out what is null, the next step is usually to figure out *why* it is null. Again, that's easy in this case. It's null because it's a field, and on the record your trigger is failing on, that field has no assigned value.

Finally, we can either fix the issue (go back to the source of the null data, and make sure it is not null) or mitigate the risk of having null data by performing a null check. In your case, mitigation is the appropriate approach.

A null check is really simple. Literally just `if(variable == null)` or `if(variable != null)`. We can also rely on the fact that Salesforce will "short-circuit" the evaluation of a boolean statement.

In other words, if you perform your null check earlier in the statement than where you use the thing that *could* be null, you will be safe from an NPE.

`if(variable != null && variable.contains('a'))` will never evaluate the `variable.contains('a')` portion if `variable` is `null` because `null != null` is false and `false && <anything>` evaluates to false.

Since we know the entire statement will evaluate to false, we don't need to (and Salesforce, and many other languages as well, won't) evaluate the rest of the statement.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

When a string has no value, it will appear as "null". If you try to call a method on a null object, you'll get a NullPointerException. To fix this, check for the null value first:

```
trigger RadarFirst on Patient_Satisfaction__c (before update) {
    for (Patient_Satisfaction__c cc : Trigger.new){
        if(cc.Patient_Relation__c != null && cc.Patient_Relation__c.contains('Referred to Privacy Office')){
            RadarUpdate.postcallout(cc.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That worked. Thats a good learning for me.